# Apex oracel how do you move pages, for example, the product page continues to move pages to the product detail page

Tags: oracle-apex

[enter image description h[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c7cD.png)ere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRkzA.png)

so I have a product id column when I go to the product detail page, so how do I find the product id to appear on the product detail id page, please help so that the id link is clicked so he knows he is id 8 from his page 24 later because he the product details

so that the id link is clicked then he knows he is id 8 from his page 24 later because he details the product

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create a **link**.

Wizard - which creates an Interactive Report page that navigates to a Form page - does that automatically. Otherwise, you'll have to do it yourself.

In link properties, click the "Target" and set target page (24) and pass value from current page (P8; if it is a report, you'd pass e.g. `#PRODUCT_ID#`; if it is a form, you'd pass `&P8_PRODUCT_ID.` - note the trailing dot character!). Use **list of values** icon for both `name` and `value` so that you wouldn't have to type names yourself.

[image]

Comment: yes, I understand, but this condition is only on page 24 column, so I can't set the item